# Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript

So I'm in the process of making a tip calculator, all is fine besides one problem child... When I inspect it, it seems that the value its giving me is 'undefined'.

The purpose of it is to change the result shown in 'new-bill' based on the inputs of the other fields. 
Its corresponding line is - **document.getElementById('new-bill').innerHMTL = '£'+ newBillEach.toFixed(2);** (the second to last line).

I've ran separate tests to check if all my tags were ok, and they seem to be fine. Probably spent about four hours yesterday evening trying different things but no luck. HELP D':

https://codepen.io/ceramants/pen/MWYrXZj

```js
document.getElementById('container').onchange = function(){
    const bill = Number(document.getElementById('total-bill').value);
    const tipPercent = document.getElementById('tip-input').value;
    const split = document.getElementById('split-input').value;

    const tipValue = bill * (tipPercent/100);
    const newBillEach = (bill + tipValue) / split;
    const tipEach = tipValue / split;

    document.getElementById('tip-output').innerHTML = tipPercent +'%';
    document.getElementById('split-output').innerHTML = split;
    document.getElementById('new-bill').innerHMTL = '£'+ newBillEach.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('tip-each').innerHTML = '£' + tipEach.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F1F3F6;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

body main hr {
  border: 2px solid #F1F3F6;
  width: 80%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 2px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.123), -3px -3px 8px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.979);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 2px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.123), -3px -3px 8px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.979);
}

#container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F1F3F6;
  width: 40em;
  height: 40em;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 33%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 33%;
  -moz-border-radius: 33%;
  -ms-border-radius: 33%;
  -o-border-radius: 33%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 29px 29px 28px 13px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.1), -30px -30px 28px 13px white;
          box-shadow: 29px 29px 28px 13px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.1), -30px -30px 28px 13px white;
}

#container table {
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #48486b;
  margin: 30px 0;
  width: 80%;
}

#container table tr:hover {
  background-color: #e6e9ee;
}

#container table tr td span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#container table .left-col span {
  color: #a6a6c0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#container table .right-col span {
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#container table input {
  width: 72%;
  background-color: #F1F3F6;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #a6a6c0;
  padding: 5px;
}

header {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #141414;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inknut+Antiqua:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Tip Calculator App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <header>Tip Calculator</header>
        <section id='container'>
            <table class='row-one'>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Total Bill:</td>
                  <td class='right-col'><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your total bill..." id="total-bill"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Tip:</td>
                  <td class='right-col'>
                      <input type="range" value="0" id="tip-input" class="range">
                      <span id="tip-output">0%</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Split <span>(number of people)</span></td>
                  <td class='right-col'>
                      <input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="30" id="split-input" class="range">
                      <span id="split-output">1</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
            <table class='row-two'>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>New bill: <span>(per person)</span></td>
                  <td class='right-col'><span id="new-bill">£0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Tip Amount: <span>(per person)</span></td>
                  <td class='right-col'><span id="tip-each">£0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please convert tipPercent to a number just like you do for the bill, lets see what it gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code: you use `innerHMTL`:

```
document.getElementById('new-bill').innerHMTL = '£'+ newBillEach.toFixed(2);
/*__________________________________^^^^^^^^^_____________________________*/
```

It should be `.innerHTML` instead:

```
document.getElementById('new-bill').innerHTML = '£' + newBillEach.toFixed(2);
```

See working example here:

```js
document.getElementById('container').onchange = function(){
    const bill = Number(document.getElementById('total-bill').value);
    const tipPercent = document.getElementById('tip-input').value;
    const split = document.getElementById('split-input').value;

    const tipValue = bill * (tipPercent/100);
    const newBillEach = (bill + tipValue) / split;
    const tipEach = tipValue / split;

    document.getElementById('tip-output').innerHTML = tipPercent +'%';
    document.getElementById('split-output').innerHTML = split;
    document.getElementById('new-bill').innerHTML = '£'+ newBillEach.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('tip-each').innerHTML = '£' + tipEach.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F1F3F6;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

body main hr {
  border: 2px solid #F1F3F6;
  width: 80%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 2px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.123), -3px -3px 8px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.979);
          box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 2px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.123), -3px -3px 8px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.979);
}

#container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F1F3F6;
  width: 40em;
  height: 40em;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 33%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 33%;
  -moz-border-radius: 33%;
  -ms-border-radius: 33%;
  -o-border-radius: 33%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 29px 29px 28px 13px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.1), -30px -30px 28px 13px white;
          box-shadow: 29px 29px 28px 13px rgba(55, 84, 170, 0.1), -30px -30px 28px 13px white;
}

#container table {
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #48486b;
  margin: 30px 0;
  width: 80%;
}

#container table tr:hover {
  background-color: #e6e9ee;
}

#container table tr td span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#container table .left-col span {
  color: #a6a6c0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#container table .right-col span {
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#container table input {
  width: 72%;
  background-color: #F1F3F6;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #a6a6c0;
  padding: 5px;
}

header {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Inknut Antiqua', serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #141414;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inknut+Antiqua:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Tip Calculator App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <header>Tip Calculator</header>
        <section id='container'>
            <table class='row-one'>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Total Bill:</td>
                  <td class='right-col'><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your total bill..." id="total-bill"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Tip:</td>
                  <td class='right-col'>
                      <input type="range" value="0" id="tip-input" class="range">
                      <span id="tip-output">0%</span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Split <span>(number of people)</span></td>
                  <td class='right-col'>
                      <input type="range" value="1" min="1" max="30" id="split-input" class="range">
                      <span id="split-output">1</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
            <table class='row-two'>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>New bill: <span>(per person)</span></td>
                  <td class='right-col'><span id="new-bill">£0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class='left-col'>Tip Amount: <span>(per person)</span></td>
                  <td class='right-col'><span id="tip-each">£0.00</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```